# How to Interact w/ Items from NodeList Iterating Through Them One After Another Not Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, ecmascript-5, nodelist

I have a form with address rows. Each row has a link (.address-row a.a-link-normal) that when clicked a pop-up shows up. The pop-up has a button #delete-address-popover-button-announce this button needs to be clicked, which opens another confirmation dialog with button .rm-address-button this also gets clicked and one address row is deleted.

I want do this automatically with JavaScript. I tried all kinds of code variation using getElementsByClassName for live HTMLcollection, using querySelectorAll for static NodeList. Tried overloading NodeList, converting it to Array with .slice , placing the whole code in a function with setInterval ... each variant I tried has either no effect, or the code only deletes the first address and has no effect on the rest.

Here is the latest code variant, I also leave the comments from previous trials:

```
//function delayX() {
var addressBook = document.getElementById('address-list');
var adresRow = addressBook.querySelectorAll('.address-row a.a-link-normal');
console.log('Before for loop' + adresRow.length);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < adresRow.length; ++i) {
//Array.prototype.slice.call(adresRow).forEach(function (element) {
//element.click();
adresRow.item(i).click();
console.log('Click' + adresRow);

function delAddresses() {
    document.getElementById('delete-address-popover-button-announce').innerHTML = "Deleting..";
    document.getElementById('delete-address-popover-button-announce').click();
    console.log('delete-address-popover-button-announce here');
}
setTimeout(delAddresses, 1500);

function delConfirm() {
    document.querySelector('.rm-address-button').innerHTML = "Deleting..";
    document.querySelector('.rm-address-button').click();
    console.log('rm-address-button here');
    }
  setTimeout(delConfirm, 2500);
  }
 //});
 console.log('End for loop' + adresRow.length);
 //}
 //setInterval(delayX, 5000);
```

The odd thing is, that the FOR iterates as many times as there are items in the NodeList, which I see in the browser console by the console.log counts. It looks like the for loop iterates as many times as we want it to, however only the first address gets deleted and then the code stops. I also should mention that after address row is deleted the page gets AJAX-like refresh.

I've been working on this since yesterday and feel rather stuck at this point. Help and advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, and especially how exactly you're deleting the elements, I'd say that there's multiple same ids in the elements, maybe due to a failed removal of the element. In that case `getElementById` finds only the first element having the queried id.

Comment: The script presses the delete buttons by click(); The script works for the first row, but not for the rest. Yes, I see a warning about non-unique ids in the console, however, this is something I have no control over. I'm working with external page I did not wrote the HTML for.

Comment: Changed to querySelector instead of getElementById, same effect.

Comment: Yes, because `querySelector` also finds only the first element. Most likely the element to delete is not actually deleted, it still is in the DOM. It's hard to say how to fix the problem without seeing the HTML structure and the delete function.

Comment: Yes, but actually those non-unique IDs are not related to the HTML elements I'm working with

Comment: ?? There is a hardcoded id in `delAddresses`, how is that not related? Please show the code, otherwise this question is not answerable.

Comment: This ID is the button of a pop up window that gets closed, once the button is clicked. May be I need to clarify that this code is .js file that is being executed by a Chrome extension on Amazon checkout page. ?